# Copy / Migrate / Synchronize Active Directory Password across Domain

Tags: active-directory

I am in the middle of an Active Directory Migration and need to keep user passwords synchronized between the old and new environment.

As I want to implement a Service for getting the Job done and don't want to use the API of ADMT (Active Directory Migration Tool) I am in the need of a method to copy Passwords from the old account to the migrated one.
Does anybody know about a Windows API function that is capable of copying passwords from an account across Domains to another one - which is the migrated version of it?